# Python quicksort recursive

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

I get the error

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

while running the following code:

```
def partition(lst, start, end):
    new_lst=lst[start:end]
    pos=0
    if len(lst)<2:
        return None
    for i in range(len(new_lst)):
        if new_lst[i] < new_lst[-1]:
            new_lst[i],new_lst[pos]=new_lst[pos],new_lst[i]
            pos+=1

        elif i==(len(new_lst)-1):
            new_lst[-1],new_lst[pos]=new_lst[pos],new_lst[-1]

    return pos    

def quick_sort_recursive(lst, start, end):

    if start<end:

        pos=partition(lst, start, end)
        quick_sort_recursive(lst, start, pos-1)
        quick_sort_recursive(lst, pos+1, end)
```

Comment: How big of a list are you passing to it?

Comment: Add a `print pos` right after the `pos=partition(lst, start, end)` and your bug should become obvious.

Comment: the list is [13,54,3434,88,334,6,8,84,57,4,2,4,6,6]

Comment: and i did print pos...it was 3

Comment: guess at some point pos = end + 1

Comment: i did change it to: "if start<=pos<=end:" and it stopped running to max, but the def still doesn't work

Comment: You still have an issue where if your list get to length 2, you return `None`. But you don't account for this in the quicksort code. Note that `1<None` == `False`, while `None<1` == `True`. `None+1` should finally generate an error though.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are not modifying the original list... this code:

```
def partition(lst, start, end):
    new_lst=lst[start:end]
```

Probably you think that this just gives you a view into the original list, but this actually creates a copy. Then you partition it and send back a position... but this partitioned list is just thrown away.

You can modify the original list, but you'll need to do. The simplest way might just be to insert it back:

```
    new_lst = lst[start:end]
    # do some stuff
    lst[start:end] = new_lst
```

I'm not sure this is what's giving you recursion, but each recursive call has expectations from the previous layer, and that's not valid here.